# UIButton and other elements not accessuble inside UICollectionView when using custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a custom UICollectionViewCell which contains UILabels, UIButtons and UITextFields. The custom cell is successfully loaded and appears properly on the device screen but the problem is I cant seem to intercept any touch events on the elements of the custom cell in the collection view. 
What could be the problem?

Comment: Please consider adding some code which is used to receive the touch events for those widgets.

Comment: I didnt add any code yet for handling the touch events yet but the least i would expect when i touch the button is for it to animate, also when i touch the textfield for it to pop up the keyboard.

Comment: Is userInteraction enabled on the storyboard?

Comment: did you make sure that the cell has the CollectionViewController as delegate and dataSource? If not, it can be that you are interacting, but nothing is happening.

Comment: yes user interaction is enabled in storyboard @Kerberos

Comment: any suggestions @RatulSharker